# Iphone device software

Tags: ios, iphone, device

I'm not sure this question can be asked here, but I dont really know where I can get information. I've been doing some research and nothing obvious came out.

So here is the thing, I've developed a functionnality.

It works fine on computer.
It works fine on the Android Api.

But there is some bugs on the Iphone Api.

The thing is: I don't have any Iphone, so I can't see what's happening. Jus know what people said to my boss.
So, I'm looking for a piece of software to be able to test the API like if I was using an Iphone. I'm not just looking for something that will simulate sizes like the view from navigator development functionnality.

Do you know something like that ? It will be really helpfull thank you.

Comment: Do you mean Xcode and iOS Simulator?

Comment: In xCode you have the simulator in which you can try all your software on iPhone's and iPad's

Comment: Maybe, but not sure. Using xcode, can I download the API using an http link ? Because it's already online and i have to test it with the online version. Thanks.

Comment: You are not giving us enough information to go on, what is your API? what does it do and work? To test on iOS you will need an iOS device and a Mac with Xcode to debug an iOS app.

Comment: I don't gave those information because i don't have them neither :(
This is based on a php website and somehow from the website code the api is built (I really don't know how). So there is a link to download the api and install it.

Answer (score 0):

You need an apple computer.
Open up the project in Xcode which has an emulator.

Otherwise:
If your windows, you could try an app like Smartface: https://www.smartface.io/ios-and-android-emulator-on-windows/

Google iOS Emulators for Windows for Development and you should have lots of options to review for yourself.

Comment: I'm with windows indeed. I'm going to check Smartface.

Answer (score -1):

The iPhone simulator in xcode should be exactly what you need.

This should get you started:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Maybe, but not sure. Using xcode, can I download the API using an http link ? Because it's already online and i have to test it with the online version. Thanks.